# Is a generic object builder possible in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, expression-trees, builder

I'm writing some unit tests for a reporting system that uses some pretty complex composition of DTOs. To test the system I find myself writing a lot of code like this:

```
var items = new List<Item>
{
    new Item
    {
        Things =
            new List<Thing>
            {
                new Thing
                {
                    Stuff =
                        new Stuff
                        {
                            Widgets = new List<Widget> {new Widget {Color = "Red"}}
                        },
                    Bobbles = new List<Bobble>{new Bobble(), new Bobble()}
                }
            }
    }
};
```

This strikes me as verbose and cumbersome so my first thought was to use the builder pattern with a fluent interface:

```
var items = ItemBuilder.AddItem()
                           .WithThing()
                           .WithStuff()
                           .WithWidget()
                           .WithColor("Red");
```

Or something to that effect. Then it hit me that I have other objects I need to create like this and that it would be nice if I could use generics to apply this to any object I needed to:

```
var items = Builder.Add<Item>()
                           .With<Thing>()
                           .With<Stuff>()
                           .With<Widget>()
                           .With<Color>("Red");
```

Obviously these examples only approximate what the real interface might look like.

With such syntactic sugar as generics, lambdas and expression trees is this possible with C#?

I searched to see if anyone had attempted something like this but only found one or two incomplete series of blog posts on the topic. It seems to me that if it were possible there would be a complete example or an open source or commercial library available.

Comment: I can't see why it wouldn't be possible.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: please make that an answer so we can upvote it. :-) ...all kidding aside, though, what are you expecting out of this question? Yes, it seems possible. Do you want someone to blurt out the whole code for it? That's rather a lot of work.

Comment: Of course not. I didn't ask anyone to "give me the codez". I was hoping for confirmation (which you've given) that I wouldn't be wasting my time to attempt this and possibly a link to an article or a library where someone has already pioneered the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like NBuilder could satisfy your requirements: https://code.google.com/p/nbuilder/

It already exists, is widely used and very popular.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see why it wouldn't be possible. You might need a bit different syntax to make structure a bit more obvious, e.g.:

```
Builder.Add<Item>(i =>
           i.With<Thing>(t =>
               t.With<Stuff>(s =>
                   s.Add<Widget>(w => w.With<string>("Red"))
                    .Add<Widget>(w => w.With<string>("Green")))
                .Add<Bubble>()
                .Add<Bubble>()));
```

It assumes that there is exactly one property with given type. E.g. `With<T>` would look for a property typed as `<T>` and `Add<T>` would look for property typed `List<T>`.

It would get a bit messy when there is more than one property of given type. You'd have to somehow determine which one should be set with given Value.

```
s.Add<Widget>(w => w.With(x => x.Color, "Red").With(x => x.Name, "MyWidget"));
```

Get's ugly real quick. Also perf wouldn't be ideal, so I can't see any real usage other than crafting instances for Unit Testing.

I know nothing about existing library like this.

Answer (score 0):

If XML, JSON and XAML have teached us anything, it's that **declarative languages are much better suited to create object graphs** than imperative ones.

Forget all that and use XML, JSON or XAML de/serialization:

Here's an example of how your code would look like, using JSON:

```
"items": [
    "item": { 
       "Things": [
           "Thing": {
               "Stuff": {
                   "Widgets" [
                      "Widget": {"Color" = "Red"}
                    ],
                "Bobbles": [ 
                   "Bobble": { }],
               },
            },
        ],
     },
 },
```

Then, it's just a matter of using any of the many well-known de/serialization libraries (such as [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)), to convert your serialized data into a strongly typed object graph.

> Disclaimer: I hand-typed the above JSON so it might have syntax errors, but you get the idea.

Comment: Except that C# object initializer syntax *is* a declarative (sub-)language.